# How to make Visual Studio wait for me to compile before complaining about declared but never used variables

Tags: c#, ide, visual-studio-2017, error-checking

How to make Visual Studio wait for me to compile before complaining about declared but never used variables?

`CS0168 The variable '_' is declared but never used`

Yes Visual Studio, ofcourse it's not used, I'm still writing the code, stop distracting me.

Note, I do not want to disable the feature entirely, I just want to make it shut up for a second and not start underlining my variables before I've compiled the source.

In essence, I want to make the "check-as-you-type" feature not as dynamic but only for this error.

(I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017, if this makes any difference)

Comment: You shouldn't suppress these warnings, they're useful

Comment: I'm not trying to suppress them out right

Answer (score 1):

That is explained in [How to: Suppress Compiler Warnings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj715718.aspx):

> To suppress specific warnings for Visual C# or F#
>   In Solution Explorer, choose the project in which you want to suppress warnings.
>
> On the menu bar, choose View, Property Pages.
>
> Choose the Build page.
>
> In the Suppress warnings box, specify the error codes of the warnings that you want to suppress, separated by semicolons, and then rebuild the solution.

Comment: I do not want to suppress the warnings, I want to delay them until I either save or compile or run the program.

Comment: I don't think that's possible @HidravlikaConsult. And...what would be the point in doing that? What changes compiling or saving your code for the warning? I don't understand why would it be useful in any way...

Comment: It would be useful in that it wouldn't distract you with spurious errors and warnings until such a time that it's meaningful to evaluate your code.

Saving or compiling your code represents a boundary condition, one where you have completed some sort of block of code which is internally consistent or "whole" in a way. 

The alternative would be having random warnings and errors appear in the Error list bar at the bottom and  red underlined variables right after you write a few lines but before you get a chance to use them. It's a distraction, worse it trains the user no ignore warnings.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for called "Suppress Warnings", literally to tell those warnings to 'shut the hell up'.

- Right-click on your desired project.
- Choose "**Properties**" or `Alt + Enter` (usually located on the bottom.)
- Choose **Build** tab.
- In "Suppress warnings", type in `;0168` (as 0168 is your error code,
  and ";" is used to separate the codes)
- Save
- Enjoy!

Comment: I do not want to suppress the warnings, I want to delay them until I either save or compile or run the program.

Comment: Isn't that quite obvious anyway? `Alt + Enter` and remove the error code before you build the program.  (Or even tell VS to flag them as errors.)
Alternatively, turn off warnings. Then turn on again when you need it.